# finding motifs in list and replace (python)

Tags: python, replace

all

I have a list of items (start_codons) that need to be searched in a list (lst40) and removed.

```
start_codons = ["TTG,CTG,ATG"]
lst40=['GCTTATG', "TTGTTTT','GTCTAG']
```

I am trying to write a function which does the replacement, however, if I use the following function with .replace, it will give this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
Is there a way to apply this function to the list instead? because I guess the .replace works with strings only

```
def _cleanStop(seq):
    for start in start_codons:
                seq = seq.replace(start, "")
    return seq
_cleanStop(lst40)
```

Expected output:

```
lst40=['GCTT', "TTTT','GTCTAG']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `AttributeError`, because `seq` is a `list` and your are using replace with a `list`, which is infact a method of `str`.
`seq[0].replace(start, "")` is valid because `seq[0]` is `str`.

---

Your `start_codons` is again a `list` with one element and that element is string `"TTG,CTG,ATG"`. You can create a `list` like this `['TTG', 'CTG', 'ATG']` using `split(",")`

```
>>> start_codons = ["TTG,CTG,ATG"]
>>> start_codons = start_codons[0].split(",")
>>> print(start_codons)
['TTG', 'CTG', 'ATG']
```

---

This will give you required result.

```py
start_codons = ["TTG,CTG,ATG"]
start_codons = start_codons[0].split(",")

def _cleanStop(seq):
    for start in start_codons:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            if start in seq[i]:
                seq[i] = seq[i].replace(start, "")

    return seq

lst40 = ['GCTTATG', 'TTGTTTT','GTCTAG']

print(_cleanStop(lst40))
```

**`Output:`**

```sh
['GCTT', 'TTTT', 'GTCTAG']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could form a regex alternation of starting codons, then use `re.sub` to do a global replacement/removal:

```py
start_codons = "TTG,CTG,ATG"
regex = r'(?:' + r'|'.join(start_codons.split(",")) + r')'
lst40 = ['GCTTATG', 'TTGTTTT','GTCTAG']
output = [re.sub(regex, '', x) for x in lst40]
print(output)  # ['GCTT', 'TTTT', 'GTCTAG']
```